# from bs4 import * fails to import the class NavigableString under Python3

Tags: python, import

I am reading the "Beautiful Soup 4.0.0 documentation"
[a link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)
and encountered an import problem:
I import everything in **bs4** (BeautifulSoup4.0) under python3:

```
from bs4 import *
```

but fail to use the class **NavigableString** :

```
>>> help(NavigableString)  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'NavigableString' is not defined
```

while the class **BeautifulSoup** is available:

```
>>> help(BeautifulSoup)

Help on class BeautifulSoup in module bs4:
class BeautifulSoup(bs4.element.Tag)
|  This class defines the basic interface called by the tree builders.
...
```

However, both **NavigableString** and **BeautifulSoup** are included in the namespace of **bs4**:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> dir(bs4)  

['BeautifulSoup', 
 'BeautifulStoneSoup', 'CData', 'Comment', 
 'DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ENCODING', 'Declaration', 'Doctype', 
 'NavigableString',
 'PageElement', 'ProcessingInstruction', 'ResultSet', 'SoupStrainer', 
 'StopParsing', 'Tag', 'UnicodeDammit', '__all__', '__author__', 
 '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__copyright__', '__doc__', '__file__', 
 '__license__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 
 'builder', 'builder_registry', 'dammit', 'element', 're', 'syntax_error', 
 'warnings']
```

I know I can use **NavigableString** by:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString
```

I am confused and want to figure out the underlying mechanism.
Does it have something to do with the python package or module hierarchy?
Or the previous import statement?

```
from bs4 import *
```

Comment: Tangential remark: consider not using `import *`, ever. It confuses tools like `pyflakes`, as well as making your code less readable. (I don't understand why they didn't remove it in Python 3.)

Comment: Use instead: `import bs4` or `from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag` (and so on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bs4.__all__` [*only* contains `'BeautifulSoup'`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L24), hence that is the only name that will be imported [when you import `*`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) from `bs4`.